# Django logging creates an empty file

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm trying to use `Django Logging` so I followed some tutorials but it doesn"t seem to work, the file is created but it's empty.
Here is my code :

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'LogFile.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'app': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
}
}
```

and in the view :

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def myfunction():
    logger.info("this is a debug message!")
```

Comment: It might just be some buffering issue... and FileHandler are not safe for concurrent access anyway so it might not be such a great idea if this is supposed to run on a production server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would using a different file handler type help? 
Could it be your formatter (try the simple one?)
This is an example that I have working on one of my Django apps.

```
    'default': {
        'level':'INFO',
        'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': 'LogFile.log',
        'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
        'backupCount': 5,
        'formatter':'simple',
    },
```

[Edit : since that didnt help]
Maybe you need a less specific logger instance ?:

```
   '': {
        'handlers': ['default'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True
    },
```

Comment: maybe 'app' and 'django' dont correctly identify where you are logging, try being less specific like '' in the logger settings or maybe as an experiment try logger = logging.getLogger('app') to see if that works

Comment: when i specify the name in the getLogger function it works but when it's __name__ it doesn't

Comment: yeah, so that means to me that your loggers of 'django' and 'app' dont apply to the place you are trying to log. A logger of '' will probably apply to everywhere OR is it possible for you to be more specific? Is your 'app' logger the right name for your django application?

Comment: so in the place you are logging, what do you see if you ```print __name__```? Have you tried propogate=True

Comment: I see the name of my app, i used propagate=true in loggers

Comment: Your posted code does not show propogate=True for your app logger, are you sure it is set? Is the name of your app actually 'app'?

Comment: i tried the propagate = true on my app logger but still nothing, yes the name of my app is "app"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a section adjacent to the `loggers` section:

```
'root': {
    'level': 'DEBUG', # or whatever
    'handlers': ['file'],
},
```

which should allow events from all loggers to be output. You also need to remove the `handlers` entries from the other loggers (or else you will get duplicated messages). You don't need to set `propagate`, since the default is `True`. Note that your handler level is set to `INFO` but your loggers are set to `DEBUG` - this means you won't see any `DEBUG` messages unless you either remove the handler's level or set it to `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I decided to do like **mcolin** suggested which is to replace the `__name__` with the name of the app which works perfectly

Comment: because he didn't put it as an answer but as a comment

Comment: But he did it as a comment on his answer.